# Mathematical motivation of OPE?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, conformal-field-theory

In Peskin & Schroeder (and also Cheng which I have skimmed through) they motivate the [Operator Product Expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_product_expansion) with a lot of words.

Is there any way to motivate it mathematically, e.g. Taylor expansion or similar?

Comment: The wiki link that Qmechanic added suggests a [Laurent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) expansion is employed.

Comment: The Wikipedia page links to the Scholarpedia page on OPEs -- http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Operator_product_expansion

Comment: Look at the David Tong's lectures on String theory, where he discusses OPE in the section devoted to CFTs. In brief, OPE is just the Laurent expansion.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I'd like to recommend *Conformal Field Theory* by Di-Francesco, it is a comprehensive text which is thorough and contains many applications of conformal field theory. The text is indispensable.

---

In conformal field theory, it is often characteristic of correlation functions to diverge as points of two or more fields coincide. The operator product expansion is essentially a Laurent series, and it represents a series of operators (always understood to be in correlation functions) as the sum of well-defined operators, times a factor which diverges as points coincide.  Recall under a conformal map $z\to w(z), \bar z \to \bar w(\bar z)$, a quasi-primary field transforms as,

$$\phi'(w,\bar w) = \left( \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} \right)^{-h}\left( \frac{\partial \bar w}{\partial \bar z} \right)^{-\bar h} \phi(z,\bar z)$$

where $(h,\bar h)$ are the conformal dimensions. The scaling dimension of the field is $\Delta = h+\bar h$ and planar spin $s = h - \bar h$. An example of an operator product expansion would be,

$$T(z) \phi(w,\bar w) \sim \frac{h}{(z-w)^2} \phi(w,\bar w) + \frac{1}{z-w} \partial_w \phi(w,\bar w) + \dots$$

with stress-energy tensor $T(z)$ where it is common practice to omit terms not singular as $z\to w$. This OPE in fact defines a primary operator. The OPE can also tell us other things. Consider a free boson,

$$\mathcal{S} = \frac{1}{2}g\int d^2x \, \partial_\mu \varphi \partial^\mu \varphi$$

wherein the propagator is given by,

$$\langle \varphi(x) \varphi(y)\rangle = -\frac{1}{4\pi g} \ln(x-y)^2$$

which in complex coordinates is,

$$\langle \varphi(z,\bar z)\varphi(w,\bar w)\rangle =  -\frac{1}{4\pi g} \left[ \ln(z-w) + \ln(\bar z - \bar w)\right]$$

By differentiating we can separate the holomorphic and anti-holomorphic parts:

$$\langle \partial_z \varphi(z,\bar z) \partial_w \varphi(w,\bar w) \rangle = -\frac{1}{4\pi g} \frac{1}{(z-w)^2}$$

and similarly with $(z \leftrightarrow \bar z)$, etc. The OPE of the field with itself is then,

$$\partial \varphi(z) \partial \varphi(w) \sim -\frac{1}{4\pi g} \frac{1}{(z-w)^2}$$

Notice as $z\to w$, i.e. if we exchange fields, the OPE does not change sign; this reflects the bosonic character of $\varphi$. A similar calculation for a fermion field reveals the OPE with itself is,

$$\psi(z) \psi(w) \sim \frac{1}{2\pi g}\frac{1}{z-w}$$

Exchanging $z$ and $w$ picks up a minus sign which reflects the anti-commuting or fermionic character of the field $\psi$.

---

As aforementioned, the OPE can be thought of as a Laurent series, which means we can compute residues from it. I won't go through the whole derivation, but the homomorphic component $J_z$ of the conserved current $J_a$ under conformal transformations has an OPE,

$$J_z(z)\mathcal{O}(w,\bar w)=  \dots + \frac{\mathrm{Res}[J_z(z)\mathcal{O}(w,\bar w)]}{z-w} + \dots$$

for a generic operator $\mathcal{O}$. It's analogous to when one tries to compute residues by computing the Laurent expansion of a function, rather than through the tedious limit formula. For example, for $\sin z / z$, we have,

$$\frac{\sin z}{z} = \frac{1}{z} \left( z-\frac{1}{3!} z^3 + \dots\right) = 1 -\frac{1}{3!} z^2 + \dots$$

The $z=0$ pole is a simple pole, and from the Laurent expansion, we can conclude the residue is zero. A second example:

$$\frac{e^z}{\sin z} = \frac{1}{z} + 1 + \frac{2z}{3} + \frac{z^2}{3} + \dots$$

The pole $z=0$ is likewise simple, and this time the residue is one.

Comment: Cool. I'll go and get the Di book now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @LoveLearning: Di's book is over 900 pages, it's like the MTW Gravitation book, but for CFT :)